# How to map person age in elasticsearch so it is kept actual

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, mapping

I wonder if there is a special way to map person's birth date into an age.
Naive approach would be to index a person's current age. But the age will be different next year. Then I have to update the person doc.

I wonder if there is a more sophisticated way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to index the person's birth date and then you can use a [script field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) which will compute the age of the person till now.

For instance let's say you have a person document like this one:

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "birth_date": "1984-10-12T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Then you can issue the following query:

```
POST persons/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "age" : {
            "script" : {
                "source": "ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDateTime.parse(ctx._source.birth_date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), new LocalDateTime());"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to execute your query (in the dev tools console from Kibana) and  got this: `"reason": "constructor [java.time.LocalDateTime, <init>/0] not found"`. Any idea? I guess with a cURL I would have got the same.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: Thanks for answering: ES 7.4. I put together a solution based on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-datetime.html that I would post below.

Comment: @Herrlvan - Apparently painless supports only subset og Java spec.. Check this out  - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared.html

Answer (score 1):

Using info gathered from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-datetime.html) (ES 7.4), I computed the age in a Kibana scripted field using the "`painless`" code below:

```
POST persons/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "age" : {
            "script" : {
                "source": """
                  Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(new Date().getTime());
                  ZonedDateTime birth = doc['birth_date'].value;
                  ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of('Z'));
                  ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(birth, now)
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```